# Firebase Cloud Messaging FCM build error Cannot add task ':processDebugGoogleServices' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, gradle

I'm trying to use Push Notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging and Cordova FCM. My **google-services.json** located in root folder with **config.xml** and same file in **platforms/android/** folder. With *ionic cordova build* I got error:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
> > Cannot add task ':processDebugGoogleServices' as a task with that name already exists.

I've installs:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-support-google-services --save
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm
npm install --save @ionic-native/fcm
```

and previously by another reason:

**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus ...**

Now what I got:

**platforms/android/cordova-plugin-fcm/myapp-FCMPlugin.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenLocal()
        }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
```

**platforms/android/cordova-support-google-services/myapp-build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
ext.postBuildExtras = {
    apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
}
```

**platforms/android/project.properties**:

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.0.1
cordova.system.library.3=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-fcm/myapp-FCMPlugin.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-support-google-services/myapp-build.gradle
```

which is edited from:

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-fcm/myapp-FCMPlugin.gradle
```

**platforms/android/build.gradle** which is also edited as **project.properties**:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

**plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm/scr/android/FCMPlugin.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenLocal()
        }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
```

**plugins/cordova-support-google-services/build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
ext.postBuildExtras = {
    apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
}
```

Not sure what is wrong, advice would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you have conflicting versions of the GoogleServices plugin specified in your Gradle config:

*/plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm/scr/android/FCMPlugin.gradle*

```
com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0
```

*plugins/cordova-support-google-services/build.gradle*

```
com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0
```

You need to resolve this so the versions match.

Comment: Hello, I tried it for both as `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` or `3.2.0'`, also I tried same for all  directories listed above: 3.0.0 and 3.2.0, but in all cases I got same error

Comment: Try removing cordova-support-google-services as it's redundant. Also you'll need to remove/re-add the Android platform to apply the changes